# Launcher activity is opening after clicking notification (App is closed)

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to fire notification to my application. I have a activity named NoticeActivity which is supposed to be opened after clicking the notification bar. It works well if the application is open. **But if the application is closed, then the launcher activity is opening after clicking the notification bar.**
Here is the code for notification.

```
private static final String TAG = "PUSH NOTIFICATION:";
public  int channal_id = 6; 
//String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
        Log.d(TAG, " "+ remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
        sendNotifcation(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}

private void sendNotifcation(String body) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoticeActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Details", body);
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("BRAC SK LEARNING")
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    notificationBuilder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);

    manager.notify(001, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> When your app is in the background, Android directs notification
>   messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the
>   app launcher by default.
>
> This includes messages that contain both notification and data payload
>   (and all messages sent from the Notifications console). In these
>   cases, the notification is delivered to the device's system tray, and
>   the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your
>   launcher Activity.
>
> For insight into message delivery to your app, see the FCM reporting
>   dashboard, which records the number of messages sent and opened on iOS
>   and Android devices, along with data for "impressions" (notifications
>   seen by users) for Android apps.

[Reference here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages)

Comment: Do you think the problem lies with FCM implementation?

Comment: When your launch activity is started from a notification it contains as "Extras" all the information you need. Then you can make a decision where to navigate within your app.

Comment: Is it not possible to directly open the NoticeActivity (without opening any other activity) from the notification??

Comment: AFAIK when the app is killed the answer is no.